# Need help with hardware and software config on PIC12F675 to light up an LED

Tags: pic, configuration

I'm trying to get an output from a [PIC12F675](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41190c.pdf), but I can't seem to get it to work.
Here is my hardware setup that I breadboarded:

[image]

And here is my code programmed using a PicKit2:

```
#include <htc.h>
__CONFIG(FOSC_INTRCIO & WDTE_OFF & CPD_OFF);

void main()
{
    TRISIO = 0b111101;
    GP1 = 1;
    for(;;)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

EDIT:
fixed code, but still not functional

```
    TRISIO = 0b111110;
    GP0 = 1;
    for(;;)
```

Comment: What is the voltage on the output pin?  Maybe the LED is miswired.

Comment: 0 Volts, actually my $5 DMM is giving a reading of .01V.
No, I double checked the LED, its wired properly.

Comment: What is the value of R1? Is VCC reading 5 V?

Comment: You should connect MCLR to 5V.

Comment: R1 is 330 ohms, and yes the Vcc is reading 5V, regulator is working fine

Comment: Your program works OK on my hardware, if I delete the configuration statement.

Comment: Where are your bypass caps?

Comment: I would like to make a note to the community, this user clearly has errors somewhere in their design, otherwise they would not be asking. But they posted a question with their part number, schematic and code with an explanation of what is wrong. Why no upvotes on the question? Would you prefer a user whom also has a working system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the schematic is correct, then you are setting the wrong pin. You need to set GP0 to 1 (and alter the TRISIO accordingly too)

**EDIT** - Okay, see code below. This has been confirmed to work in MPLAB SIM using HI-Tech v9.81.  I tried to comment a bit to give an idea of what is going on. Note I turned MCLR off in the config bits.
The main thing was the Comparator needing to be disabled (CMCON, see comments/datasheet)
I added a (commented) flashing routine in the for loop for interest.
For the GPIO port pins, GPIOx, or GPx  should work fine.

```
#include <htc.h>

// Define oscillator frequency for delay routines
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000 

// Make sure config bits are correct in your version 
//(e.g. v9.61, 9.81, etc) These work in v9.81 but NOT in v9.61 
// Config bits are listed in e.g. Program Files->Hi-Tech->PICC->v9.81->include  
__CONFIG(FOSC_INTRCIO & WDTE_OFF & CPD_OFF & MCLRE_OFF);

void main()
{
GPIO = 0;               // Initialise GPIO to a known state 
ANSEL = 0x00;   // Analog inputs disabled so we can read state of pin  (e.g. in MPSIM, or needing to read-modify-write)
CMCON = 0x07;           // Comparator peripheral turned off 
TRISIO = 0b11111110;    // Set GPIO0 to output  

GPIO0 = 1;              // Note GPIO0 used, not GP0 (see 12F675 include file in directory mentioned above)

for(;;)
{
    /*
    GPIO0 = 1;              // Uncomment to flash GPIO0
    __delay_ms(100);        // Hi-Tech "built in" delay routine - needs _XTAL_FREQ (oscillator frequency) defining 
    GPIO0 = 0;
    __delay_ms(100);
    */
}
```

}

Comment: The analogue input function on that pin only applies if it is being used as a digital input!

Comment: Lol, good point - wasn't thinking :-)

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. +1 to cancel the downvote.

Comment: Just made the fix, but pin GP0 still is not turning on. :(

Comment: As Olin mentioned MCLR is floating and you have not disabled it with the config bits. Either connect it to Vdd with an e.g. 10k resistor, or set the config bit appropriately (I think it's something like MCLRE_DIS in Hi-Tech, but you can check the device header file - usually at the bottom. Or override config bits in code in MPLAB using Configure->Configuration Bits).

Comment: I tried doing that. I put a 10K resistor between the Vcc pin and the MCLR pin, but it still did not work.

Then in MPLAB I went to Configure>Configuration Bits and made the following settings:

-INTOSC, IO function on GP4 and GP5
-WDT disabled
-PWRT disabled
-GP3/MCLR pin is IO, MCLR internally tied to Vdd
-BOD disabled
-program memory code protection disabled
-data memory protection disabled. but even that was not successful.

Comment: It's driving me nuts, I've been trying to learn the pic programming process for a week now and I'm not making much progress...any other ideas why its not working?

Comment: Have you got a bypass capacitor across the PICs Vcc and GND pins? (e.g. 0.1uF)

Comment: @Shubham - see edited answer. Try this and let me know how it goes, hopefully it should work. As Olin says, please have a good read of the datasheet ;-)

Comment: Hey it worked! I completely started over, added the bypass cap, used the code you provided, and it the pin turned on! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have the MCLR input floating!  That can obviously keep the part from running, but is a bad idea even if it's configured as a general logic input.

Comment: Is the MCLR pin used by this configuration, or is it just another GPIO? Does it have an internal pullup?

Comment: What is the purpose of the MCLR?I tried doing that by connecting pin 1 and 4 (Vcc and MCLR), but still no avail

Comment: @Shubham: If you don't know what MCLR does, then you need to seriously READ THE DATASHEET.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
TRISIO = 0b111110;
GP0 = 1;
```

With the configuration statement deleted your original program works OK on my hardware, using a different output for the LED (GP2).

The problem is caused by & CPD_OFF. With that deleted the program works.

Comment: Oh silly mistake, but even after that fix, its not working. Is the __CONFIG ok? I had compile errors until with it until I read the include file to figure out the right config bits